# Impact of deploying webservices implemented in Play Framework onto Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, playframework-2.0

If I develop RESTservices using Play Framework in Java (with Akka) and deploy it on Tomcat(non-NIO or NIO) instead of running these on embedded Netty server, what would be the effect of this combination? Will its performance or other criteria be the same as it would have been in embedded Netty server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You're using it in a way that we (the core play team) don't test or really consider when we make changes. Minor upgrades could break everything.
2. Play's asynchronous from the ground up approach is not a good fit for the servlet APIs bolt on asynchronous support as an after thought approach. I suspect performance will be an issue, though I've never seen benchmarks.
3. The Servlet specs support for asynchronous IO is woeful. A couple of small interfaces with one liner comments. Completely underspecified, no guidance as to how edge cases are handled, no guidance as to the concurrency aspects. I helped with reviews/guidance in implementing the play war plugin support with it, what was found is that jetty, tomcat and glassfish all differed significantly in their interpretation of the spec (what do you expect when the methods they are implementing just have one liner comments that day nothing about the complex semantics of async IO), this is a major issue for Play.
4. If you're not using a Servlet 3.1 container, then the story is worse, with the mixing of async and sync IO, deadlocks under high load will abound.
5. A number of core Play features simply can't be implemented on the servlet spec. Chunked encoding is one.

There's just a few problems.